# How to debug the linux kernel on the real machine using gdb?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, gdb, gdbserver

I have a HP Pavilion 15 laptop with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS installed. I was using 6.2.0-39-generic kernel version. I compiled the 6.7.0-rc8-next-20240103 kernel version from [source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/) after creating a new branch from the tag `next-20240103`. I followed the official kernel docs and found that the kernel config for debugging were already set using `make localmodconfig`. I was able to boot into this linux-next kernel successfully.

Now to solve a bug in the 6.7.0-rc8-next-20240103 kernel, I thought of debugging the kernel using `gdb`. Basically I need to find in which function a particular NULL pointer (which should not be a NULL pointer) was assigned and where, how and why I was getting the NULL pointer dereference in the first place. Note this bug occurs on waking up from suspension.

In one terminal tab, I ran:

```sh
$ gdbserver --attach :1234 1
```

I think ACPI driver is initialzed by init (pid 1).

In another tab, I ran:

```sh
$ cd src/linux-next
$ gdb vmlinux
 Reading symbols from vmlinux...
 (gdb) tar remote :1234
 warning: Build ID mismatch between current exec-file /home/username/src/linux-next/vmlinux
 and automatically determined exec-file /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
 exec-file-mismatch handling is currently "ask"
 Load new symbol table from "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd"? (y or n) n
 (gdb) hbreak drivers/acpi/acpica/evregion.c:131
 Hardware assisted breakpoint 1 at 0xffffffff8197e240: drivers/acpi/acpica/evregion.c:131. (2   locations)
 (gdb) step
 warning: Remote failure reply: E01
 Ignoring packet error, continuing...
 Ignoring packet error, continuing...
 Ignoring packet error, continuing...
 Ignoring packet error, continuing...
 Ignoring packet error, continuing...
 Ignoring packet error, continuing...
```

The last state of gdbserver was as follows:

```sh
$ sudo gdbserver --attach :1234 1 
Attached; pid = 1
Listening on port 1234
Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1, port 52364
gdbserver: Couldn't write debug register: Invalid argument.
Listening on port 1234
input_interrupt, count = 1 c = 36 ('$')
```

First, the breakpoint 1 should only be at 1 location. Second, I don't get why there is error on step command in both `gdb` and `gdbserver`.

Is it the right way to do remote kernel debugging on the same machine? If not, what is the right way?

I have a MacBook Pro too as my second machine. If needed, I can use it to run `gdb`. I really need to debug and solve this ACPI error.

Comment: You can't use gdb this way (on the same machine), because gdb needs some runtime to use stepping, but you wanna stop that runtime, so it doesn't make sense at all. If you wanna debug that was on real machine you should (1) use kdb, (2) build with sanitisers (UBSAN, KASAN, etc.). Or to spot ACPI error you likely can use QEMU/Bochs for that with sanitisers and gdb.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4943857/1216776

Comment: You are attaching `pid=1` which is the `init` process, _not_ the kernel.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Yes. Actually the `gdbserver` program needs a program or pid to attach to. I'm not sure of how you can access the kernel process (sorry newbie here) and I think init process initializes the ACPI driver... Do you know the correct process to debug linux kernel on the real machine?

Comment: "*process to debug linux kernel ...*" - There's always the tried & true method of using printk() statements. Or use an ASSERT() macro; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359700/using-assertion-in-the-linux-kernel

Comment: There is no single evidence it's related to ACPI anyhow. Dropped the tag.